# how to get list of files stored in a .qrc Qt Resorce file?

Tags: qt, embedded-resource

I'm very new to Qt..and in my program i have added some icon files in .qrc resource file.

How can we list in our program the files stored in qrc ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Here's example code that should do it:

```
QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();
}
```

Link to documentation:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html