# In Qt, use resources not located in the source directory

Tags: qt

I need to use a set of resources from several different programs (images, fonts, txt files, etc). So I put them in a common folder. So I try to read one of these txt files using this path:

```
":/../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/English"
```

However this does not work as the the QFile cannot be opened for reading with this path.

Hoewever if I move the report_text directory to the source directory and use this path:

```
":/report_text/English"
```

Then it all works just fine.

So my question is, is it possible to user resources not located in the source directory?

EDIT:

Here is my .qrc source file (and I replaced stuff.txt with an actual file from my resource file)

```xml
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/English</file>
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/GothamBlackRegular.otf</file>
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/GothamBold.otf</file>
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/GothamBook.otf</file>
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/GothamLight.otf</file>
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/GothamMedium.otf</file>
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/Spanish</file>
        <file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/viewmind.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: You could also indicate the path relationship between your source code, the .qrc and the English file

Comment: It is exactly what you see in the qrc code. Two levels up gets you to the directory that contains CommonClasses and from there, it is written above. Ohh and the qrc file is in the same folder as the .pro file and all of my sources

Answer (score 3):

The `alias` keyword is useful for giving things a different name in the resource system.

Instead of

```
<file>../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/viewmind.png</file>
```

you'd write

```
<file alias="report_text/viewmind.png">../../CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/viewmind.png</file>
```

Of course, this is bit of a pain if you're manually maintaining large qrc files; it may be useful to automate (script) production of them.

Comment: Thansk for the tip. But my program still cannot read the file. I tried to give an alias and attempted to read the alias and it is same result....

Comment: Strange (although maybe a Windows quirk).  You can enumerate what resources you app actually contains using this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13509799/24283 ; might reveal whether they're getting compiled in with a different path, or being missed completely.

Comment: I'll try it! Thanks!!1

Comment: @aarelovich I use aliases in the same way in Windows without any problem. Be sure you use the `:/` prefix as usual with QRC paths (`:/report_text/viewmind.png`).

Comment: @ cbuchart, are your resources located in a different directroy than your sources folder?

Answer (score 1):

Thank to the friendly tip @timday, I've managed to see what the problem is. The `../../` that I used were the problem. The path to the file was actually:

```
:/CommonClasses/PNGWriter/report_text/English
```

Now it works just as expected!! I hope this helps anyone else with this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a native option, as when I try to add files above the project sub-directory I get `"The file "/path/to/file/" is not in a subdirectory of the resource file. You now have the option to copy this file to a valid location."`, with the copy option.

However, (if on linux) adding a symbolic link to the resource file in the project subdirectory works perfectly fine for me. So something like `ln -s /path/to/target/resource /path/to/project/directory/resource_name.file`, and then adding resource_name.file to your resources file should work. It does on mine (Qt 5.7).

Comment: Feared as much. And I thought about the ln, however my applications is window exclusive so... Copying the files multiple times it is... Thanks

Comment: Ah, well. Best of luck. For what it's worth, [NTFS supports symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), although I've never used them.